What is bothering my peach, apple, cherry and pear trees?
These pics are from my peach, but I see similar things on some of my other three's branches and trunks as well. They are definitely not ants, I don't see any ants (or any other visible bugs on them) What is the issue, how to cure them? Please help.

The remains on the trunk/branches almost look like the dirt we see around ant hills, but don't see any ants around them. I remember seeing them long time ago in my roses and eventually the roses died breaking on a windy day - may be related to it. And I think the biggest concern now is its spreading to all my trees I think - so I'm seeing it on Peach, Cherry, Apple & Pear. Pomegranate, Banana, Lemon, Grapes, Figs, Avocado and Persimmon seems to resist them by themselves, didn't see any of the signs in them.


Based on your description and images, the culprit seems to be some type of wood-boring insect. I would immediately get in touch with an arborist or pest controller, because if they confirm my suspicions this could be a serious issue that may spread further than your yard.
